# vertical editing in vim - replacing text

Tags: vim

If I want type the same text in many lines I use:
`ctrl-v`, then `I`, typing, `esc`

so I can make fast changes from:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
...
```

to:

```
123aaa
123bbb
123ccc
123ddd
...
```

but it doesnt work if I use `del` while typing.
and i must do column replace in 2 steps: removing unwanted characters from column (`ctrl-v` + `x`), then typing like above.

is it possible to improve editing and do it in single operation?
sth like:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
...
```

to:

```
123aa
123bb
123cc
123dd
...
```

Comment: What about regex : use this %s/\v(\w\w)\w/123\1/g

Comment: regex will be pain here (slower typing, less comfortable)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can select the first column and do `c123<Esc>`:

```
[a]aa
[b]bb
[c]cc
[d]dd

c123<Esc>

123aa
123bb
123cc
123dd
```

In visual-block mode, `s` is equivalent to `c`. You can also use `d` and `x` to cut the selection, `rx` to replace every character in the selection with `x` and of course `y` to yank the whole block. You can also use `p` to paste but you need to be careful with what you paste.

Comment: To add clarity, please add the "<esc>:" to the end of the first sentence of your answer, so it would be than "You can select the first column and do c123<esc>:".